# If a given matrix A have the same eigenvalues that another matrix say B, then A and B are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to make an argument that uses that if a given matrix A have p eigenvalues and if I'm asked to check if A is diagonalizable, then I can take another matrix B that have the same p eigenvalues but that maybe the matrix B is easiest to work with. This is to save calculations.

But I dont know if the statement is a valid one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a nilpotent matrix and the zero matrix.